# Admin can not see External Lists

Tags: permissions

I have two users, one can create an `External List` and the other cannot. The one that can't, is the `machine Admin account` that is running SharePoint site from the machine and with `run as administrator` from IE.

I have no idea. Can anyone let me know the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine Admin means Farm Admin? Looks like your farm admin doesn't have access to External list, you have to set the permission for that account as you did with other users...
Farm admin does not get automatic access to content.

Comment: thats the thing. The others.. I did nothing to set them. So access to External Lists is an explicit security setting that needs to be set? extremely frustrating that at min there isnt a message as such. They just made it not visible which is the worst option I could think of. Sorry really hating SharePoint at the moment

Comment: I add the Farm Account to the Site collection admin which I would assume would already be there. Regardless. Even with that account I still can not see External Content Types when creating an External List via the browser (which is a different 'core' problem)